# taking sorted array and value in a function and placing that value in correct location

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I am having problem in this particular question, Please guide me with simple c++. in a function we have to take 2 arguments one is sorted array and the other is value, function should place that value in correct location so that array remains in sorted order. There will be a use of pointers but i m confused in this question just guide me how to make use of pointers in this particular question. It would be better if you provide me with the sample good on how it works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guiding you with simple [tag:c++]: `for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) { /* tryeit yourself first */ }`

Comment: Cut the noise. ("I am having problem... Please guide me with... Thanks in advance")

Comment: C++ arrays cannot be resized. Do you want to allocate a new array containing the same elements as the old array plus the new element?

Answer (score 2):

Seems trivial:

```
template <typename T>
int insert(T* array, int size, T const& value) {
    T* position = std::upper_bound(array, array + size, value);
    std::rotate(position, array + size, array + size + 1);
    *position = value;
    return size + 1;
}
```

Comment: lol. I'm not sure this will help the OP much. But I guess that's more or less the point

Comment: @sehe: well, the OP may not be able use this solution straight away but it shows the necessary steps. If nothing else, it is a solution which hopefully yields some interesting insight.

Comment: I must say I find this a tad on the overblown side. Any reason to shun `std::rotate`? `rit.base()` implied conversions aren't exactly intuitive to me

Comment: @sehe: hm. You're right - as Sean Parent mentions in his [GoingNative 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013) talk ["C++ Seasonsing"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning) `std::rotate()` is highly useful. I shall correct my solution correspondingly! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: difficult to understand, I am new to c++, please just explain in words me how to do this problem??

Comment: @user3100177: Well there are three steps: 1. find the location where the key should go. 2. make space by moving all elements after the key one position forward. 3. put the value into the location.

Comment: More direct might be: `auto insertion=end(a), last=next(insertion); *insertion=value; inplace_merge(begin(a), insertion, last);` (leaving bounds checking as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: @sehe: I think it would result in _O(n)_ comparisons while first locating the positions and then just shuffling objects around takes only _O(ln n)_ comparisons. For `int` that doesn't matter but, e.g., for `std::string` it might. Also, that gets further away from the algorithm the OP really needs to implement, I'd think...

Comment: @DietmarKühl step #1 get it correct, try to make the code express the task (merge an element with a sorted range...). Step #2: optimize. You're right, it isn't efficient, but there is slightly less room for programmer error.